# Finding the expectation of the given expression

Tags: probability, expectation

Suppose we have a random variable $\theta= U[0,1]$
and we have

X= 2 if $\theta\leq 0.25$ and

X=1 if $ 0.25\leq\theta \leq 1$

How would we compute the Expectation of X in this case?

Comment: Calculate by conditioning on $\theta$ :
$$E[X]=\sum_i E[X|E_i]\mathbb{P}(E_i)$$

Comment: I was given that the expression should be 

$Pr(\theta \leq 0.25)\int_{0}^{0.25} 2 (\frac{1}{0.25})d\theta+ Pr(\theta >0.25)\int_{0.25}^{1} 1\frac{1}{1-0.25}d\theta$

But i do not understand why we have to divide by $\frac{1}{0.25}$ or $\frac{1}{1-0.25}$ also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a simple problem and it's hard to see the usage of what you wrote in the comment :

$\begin{array}{ll}E[X] & =E[X|\theta\leq0.25].P(0\leq\theta\leq0.25)+E[X|\theta\leq0.25].P(0.25\leq\theta\leq1)\\
& = E[2].\frac{0.25}{1} + E[1].\frac{0.75}{1}= 2(0.25)+1(0.75)
\end{array}$

Now, consider this problem :

$X(\theta)=\left\{ \begin{array}{ll} 
2 & ;\theta\in(0,0.25]\\
\theta^2 & ;\theta\in(0.25,1)
\end{array}\right.$

Now again by conditioning we have :

$$E[X]=E[X(\theta)|\theta\leq0.25].P(0\leq\theta\leq0.25)+E[X(\theta)|\theta\leq0.25].P(0.25\leq\theta\leq1)$$
Therefore, to calculate $E[X(\theta)|\theta\leq0.25]$, you should use **[truncated distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truncated_distribution)** of $\theta$ with the condition $\theta\leq0.25$. Here is the where the statement $\frac{1}{0.25}$ emerges !

If you have questions, comment it below.